# Объединение двух массивов корректировкой данных

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте! Имеется два массива одинаковые по структуре. Нужно из более нового массива перенести данные с корректировкой в более старую,т.е. Если у пользователя Admin был 1$ в старом массиве и 5$ в новом, то в конечном массиве будет 1+5=6$. Но нужно еще делать проверку, если данные не изменились у пользователя, то тогда не производить суммирование + если в старом массиве нету пользователя из нового, то добавить все данные о нем. Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать это?

```
//Старый массив
$array1 = array(
  array('name' => 'admin1','money' => '1'),
  array('name' => 'admin2','money' => '2'),
  array('name' => 'admin3','money' => '3'),
  array('name' => 'admin4','money' => '4'),
  array('name' => 'admin5','money' => '5')

);
//Новый массив
$array2 = array(
  array('name' => 'admin1','money' => '6'),
  array('name' => 'admin2','money' => '7'),
  array('name' => 'admin3','money' => '8'),
  array('name' => 'admin4','money' => '9'),
  array('name' => 'admin5','money' => '10')

);
//Итоговый массив
$array2 = array(
  array('name' => 'admin1','money' => '7'),
  array('name' => 'admin2','money' => '9'),
  array('name' => 'admin3','money' => '11'),
  array('name' => 'admin4','money' => '13'),
  array('name' => 'admin5','money' => '15')

);
```

Comment: Ну, на скорую руку, с доп. массивом для сохранения состояний (чтобы не портить исходные данные), у меня получилось использовать: `foreach/as` - 3 раза, `break` - 1 раз, `isset` - 1 раз. То есть функция для этого пригодилась только одна, `isset`.

Вы для начала попробуйте хоть что-то написать, алгоритм действий ведь уже расписан полностью. Что конкретно вызывает сложности: как пройтись в цикле по массиву? Как сравнить два элемента? Как добавить элемент в новый массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ж сами уже расписали что нужно делать. Проходимся по первому массиву, ищем данные каждого текущего элемента по ключу 'name' во втором массиве. Нашли - в результат записываем или неизменённые данные, или новые. Из второго массива обработанный элемент удаляем (или помечаем как обработанный, если массив нужно сохранить). Не нашли - добавляем в результат текущий элемент из первого массива. В конце добавляем в результат всё, что осталось во втором массиве.

---

```
$rc = array(); // сюда пишем результат
$added = array(); // здесь храним данные про уже обработанные элементы
foreach( $array1 as $haystack )
{
    $found = 0;
    foreach( $array2 as $needle )
    {
        if( isset($added[$needle['name']]) ) 
            continue; // этот уже добавили, дальше

        if( $needle['name'] == $haystack['name'] )
        {
            if( $needle['money'] != $haystack['money'] )
                $needle['money'] += $haystack['money'];
            $rc[] = $needle;
            $added[$needle['name']] = 1;
            $found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    // не нашли во втором массиве - добавляем исходный элемент первого
    if( !$found ) $rc[] = $haystack; 
}

// и добиваем остаток второго массива
foreach( $array2 as $needle )
{
    if( !isset($added[$needle['name']]) )
        $rc[] = $needle;
}
```

Comment: Написал то что мог объяснить словами, но как это реализовать в коде, а точнее какими функциями?

Answer (score 1):

Делал похожую штуку для сравнения двух очень длинных списков, которые не влезают в память целиком. Обязательные условия: списки отсортированы, и не имеют повторов внутри каждого по отдельности.

Двигаемся параллельно по двум массивам. На каждом шаге сравниваем ключ. Если "вперед убежал" один - дочитываем следущим шагом другой, отстающий. Когда дошли до конца одного из них, хвост другого целиком копируется в результат.

[Код на ideone](http://ideone.com/poWFHL).

```
//Старый массив
$array1 = array(
    array('name' => 'admin1','money' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'admin2','money' => '2'),
    array('name' => 'admin3','money' => '3'),
    array('name' => 'admin4','money' => '4'),
    array('name' => 'admin5','money' => '5') 
);

//Новый массив
$array2 = array(
    array('name' => 'admin11','money' => '6'),
    array('name' => 'admin2','money' => '7'),
    array('name' => 'admin3','money' => '8'),
    array('name' => 'admin7','money' => '9'),
    array('name' => 'admin1','money' => '2')
);

// можно не сортировать, если известно, что имена идут по возрастанию
usort( $array1, "byName");
usort( $array2, "byName");

// перемотать указатель на первые элементы
reset( $array1);
reset( $array2);

$result = array();
$a = current( $array1);
$b = current( $array2);
while( TRUE) {
    $sign = min(1, max(-1, strcmp( $a['name'], $b['name']))); // -1, 0 или 1
    switch( $sign) {
        case 0:
            if( $a['money'] != $b['money'] ) {
                $a['money'] += $b['money'];
            }
            array_push( $result, $a);
            $a = next( $array1);
            $b = next( $array2);
        break;
        case 1:
            array_push( $result, $b);
            $b = next( $array2);
        break;
        case -1:
            array_push( $result, $a);
            $a = next( $array1);
    }

    // не подошли ли к концу?
    if( $a === FALSE) {
        rest_of( $array1, $result);
        break;
    }
    if( $b === FALSE) {
        rest_of( $array1, $result);
        break;
    }
}

// вывод результата
foreach( $result AS $a) printf( "%s: €%s\n", $a['name'], $a['money']);

function byName( $a, $b) { // сортировка по полю name
    return strcmp( $a['name'], $b['name']);
}

function rest_of( &$arr, &$result){ // дописать остаток массива в $result
    while( ($a = next( $arr)) !== FALSE) {
        array_push( $result, $a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменил массивы и сделал такой алгоритм

```
foreach($array3 AS $key => $value){
    foreach($array4 AS $key1 => $value1){
        if($key == $key1 AND $value != $value1){
            $array5=array($key1 => $value+$value1);
            foreach ($array5 as $name =>$money){
                echo $name."=>".$money."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

После чего все идеально, кроме условия если нету элемента в 1 массиве, но есть во втором, то его надо добавить к первому.

Сами массивы выглядят так теперь

```
$array4 = array(
                'admin1' => '1',
                'admin2' => '2',
                'admin3' => '3',
                'admin4' => '4',
                'admin5' => '5');
```

Comment: Ну вот, уже что-то :) Хоть и неправильно. Сейчас пост обновлю.